# spring mvc-adding a object to the request

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring-mvc and have a basic question.
I have a controller that reads the parameters that are sent in from a jsp and adds an object called userInfo to the ModelAndView and passes on to another jsp. The second jsp displays the vaious properites of the userInfo. 
How do I send back the userInfo object to the controller?

```
 <td><input type="hidden" name="userInfo" value="${requestScope.userInfo}"/></td>
```

I try to read the userInfo in the controller as follows:

```
request.getAttribute("userInfo")
```

However, this is null.
What is the best way for me to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the applicable code for your controller?

Comment: In the jsp, I am passing it as a hidden field as follows:
 <td><input type ="hidden" name ="userInfo" value = "${requestScope.userInfo}"/></td>

In the controller this is how I am reading it

    UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) request.getAttribute("userInfo");

Comment: I'd look into the @RequestParam annotation as suggested in the answer below, that's why I was curious about your controller code.  I don't use request.getAttribute() in any of my Spring controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML `<form>` `<input>` elements are sent as url-encoded parameters. You need to access them with [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

```
request.getParameter("userInfo");
```

Or use the `@RequestParam` annotation on a handler method parameter

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String myHandler(@RequestParam("userInfo") String userInfo) {
   ...
}
```

Note however, that **this won't send back the object, it will send back a `String`** which is the `toString()` value of the object because that is what is given with `${requestScope.userInfo}`.

Consider using session or flash attributes to have access to the same object in future requests.